# Referencing a Partner through AccountToId but can't reach Name

Tags: visualforce, email-template, partner

I am writing a VF email template which should build a table of the related partners to the opportunity.
when I pull the partner details from the {!relatedTo.Partners} object I can't reach [Name] for the related account in the [AccountToId] relationship.
here is my code:

```
    <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Congratulations {!relatedTo.owner.name} on closing another deal!" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Opportunity" replyTo="sal******lp@********.com">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<HTML>
    <body style="font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'">
        <h2>
            Deal overview:</h2>
        <hr style="border: solid thin #0099CC; margin-top: -18px;" />
        <br />
        <table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="60%">
            <tr>
                <td align="right" 
                    style="border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: thin; border-right-color: #0099CC;" 
                    width="30%">
                    <i>Account Executive</i>
                </td>
                <td width="70%">
                    <b>{!relatedTo.owner.name}</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" 
                    style="border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: thin; border-right-color: #0099CC;" 
                    width="30%">
                    <i>Account Name: </i>
                </td>
                <td width="70%">
                    <b>{!relatedTo.Account.Name}</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" 
                    style="border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: thin; border-right-color: #0099CC;" 
                    width="30%">
                    <i>Opportunity Type: </i>
                </td>
                <td width="70%">
                    <b>{!relatedTo.Type}</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" 
                    style="border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: thin; border-right-color: #0099CC;" 
                    width="30%">
                    <i>Total Amount: </i>
                </td>
                <td width="70%">
                    <b>{!relatedTo.Amount} (USD ~{!relatedTo.Amount_converted__c})</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      <br />
      <h3>
            Involved Team:</h3>
        <hr style="border: solid thin #0099CC; margin-top: -18px;" />
        <br />
        <table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #0099CC; color: #FFFFFF">
                    <b>Name</b>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #0099CC; color: #FFFFFF">
                    <b>Role</b>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <apex:repeat var="team" value="{!relatedTo.OpportunityTeamMembers}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {!team.User.Name}

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {!team.TeamMemberRole}
                        </td>

                    </tr>
            </apex:repeat> 
        </table>
            <br />
      <h3>
            Channel Information:</h3>
        <hr style="border: solid thin #0099CC; margin-top: -18px;" />
        <br />
        <table cellpadding="5" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #0099CC; color: #FFFFFF">
                    <b>Partner Name</b>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #0099CC; color: #FFFFFF">
                    <b>Role</b>
                </td>

            </tr>

            <apex:repeat var="partner" value="{!relatedTo.Partners}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {!partner.AccountToId.Name}

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {!partner.Role}
                        </td>

                    </tr>
            </apex:repeat> 
        </table>

    </body>
    </HTML>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

My problem is with this line: `{!partner.AccountToId.Name}`
it gives me the error: "Unknown property 'String.Name'"

What I want to achieve is a table with the Partner's name in the first column and the partner's role in the second column. Second column works fine but the first column only returns ID when I use  {!partner.AccountToId}

Can anybody help?

Thanks!

Comment: For standard objects usually field names that end in "Id" contain the ID value of the referenced object, and there is the same name but without the "Id" that can have a reference to the object itself, in this case `{!partner.AccountTo.Name}`. (You can use e.g. the Force.com IDE's schema view to find these names.) But the query that provides the data must have included the referenced object and field; I'm unsure in this context whether that will be done automatically or not so best to try it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the id: {!partner.AccountTo.Name}